# ServiceStack validation for multiple properties

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

How do I write the validation rule if I want to check if at least one of the properties in the request DTO is not empty?

I can do it individually, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine multiple to do something like - check if at least one of FirstName, LastName and CompanyName has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) question, you can use `When()` to selectively apply the rule, e.g:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
    .NotEmpty()
    .When(x => (x.LastName ?? x.CompanyName).IsNullOrEmpty());
```